# Is there a way to clone selected github repos?

Tags: bash, github, command-line-interface, zsh, git-bash

Through the GH CLI, I'm trying to create a filtered list within my Org and only clone those repos.

For example, I only want to clone repos with the title terraform-datadog-*-oac, * being the service names.

I have tried these:

Cant seem to filter using these -

```
gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" /orgs/open-itg/repos --paginate --jq '.[].name'

gh repo list open-itg --limit 500 | while read -r repo _; do if [[ $repo =~ "^(open-itg/terraform-datadog*)" ]]; done
```

Please let me know the best method for this. Trying to keep track of my project repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by running this.

```
gh repo list open-itg --limit 9999 | grep open-itg/terraform-datadog- | while read -r repo _; do
  gh repo clone "$repo"
done
```